# Can't add or remove files on SD card

Tags: sd-card

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 (SC-04F). It has a stock ROM, not rooted, recently upgraded to Android 6.0.1.

After upgrading to Android Marshmallow, No application seems to be able to add, remove, or edit files on the external SD card. For example, [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync&hl=en), can not download files to the SD card, [n7player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n7mobile.nplayer&hl=en) can not remove music files, [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en) can't move or edit pictures. These are just examples... no app on my phone seems to be able to access the SD card.

*Reading* files is okay. n7player can play music, and Quickpic can view images, but no app can make changes to the SD card.

If I connect the phone by USB to either my Linux or Windows computer, I can add or remove files from the SD card just fine.

I tried reformatting the SD card, and that didn't change anything.

Whenever I try to take action on a file from within any app, I'm always given this screen:

[image: SD Card problem screen 1]

I follow through by pressing "Got it", and then I am shown the following interface:

[image: SD Card problem screen 2]
[image: SD Card problem screen 3]

Unfortunately, though, nowhere in this interface can I find any option to change permissions on my SD card, or even act on it in any way at all.

In the top left, there is a three dot icon, and if I press it, it gives me the alternate options of either "Show SD Card" or "Hide SD Card". However selecting either option changes nothing.

How do I make my SD card available for use by the apps on my phone?

Comment: You should find SD card when you press the menu option button left  of recent. In case you don't  go to Settings > Apps > Show System Apps and find External Storage and Media Storage and clear data and cache on each one and reboot, then give it some time after full boot up to rebuild media databases

Comment: Do the above after removing and reinserting SD card

Comment: @beeshyams, Thanks for responding. I followed your instructions, but unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Comment: Unfortunate. Let's wait for other options. I had a somewhat similar problem and it took three attempts of repeating the process if i recollect right. Your problem may be different but it may help to repeat a few times

Comment: You could give this app a try - [local storage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ianhanniballake.localstorage)

Comment: @beeshyams, thank you for suggesting the Local Storage app. It provides its own interface for editing files on the SD card, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have the ability to change the permissions or capabilities of any other apps.